# How to create an account on Google Apps to use Google Apps Extensions Console?

Tags: google-docs, google-apps, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I am asking this question because the information on tutorials is terribly vague for a novice. Concretely, I am trying to put up an extractor to use in Gmail Contextual App. Here is where it gets complicated. To make a Gmail Contextual App, I need to upload my app code as extractor on Google Apps Extensions Console, but I am just unable to access or know where is this page. All it say [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/extensions-console/?csw=1#project) is that

`Point your browser to http://code.google.com/googleapps/console/a/yourDomainName.`

Well I did exactly that, considering a project at `code.google.com` doesn't have any place to upload an extractor, and pointed to instead

http://code.google.com/googleapps/console/a/GodKnowsWhatTheHeckIsThis

Where `GodKnowsWhatTheHeckIsThis` is completly arbitrary, I was expecting some magic here that somehow I will be taken to a project that I have not even created.

Well what happened instead is: infinite recursion.

Can you please help me here? I will be terribly grateful.