# How (and where) to upload manifest file? (Google Gmail Gadget)

Tags: google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I'm new on this Gmail Gadget developments and I follow the instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets

I follow the Hello World example, replacing the variables with my owns, generating the manifest, the specs, etc.

But when it comes to upload the manifest file, it's saying to go to 
http://code.google.com/googleapps/console/a/yourDomainName
and log in there. Then there is a serie of steps depending on this one.

The problem here is, what is the address I have to put there? I did register on the Google Apps (for bussiness) and register a domain. Still that domain isn't work.

I found several people with the same problem and none gave them a solution:

[How to create an account on Google Apps to use Google Apps Extensions Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300325/how-to-create-an-account-on-google-apps-to-use-google-apps-extensions-console)

[Logging into Google Apps Extension Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346523/logging-into-google-apps-extension-console)

http://grokbase.com/t/gg/google-appengine/141vmhsdqr/how-do-i-log-in-to-google-apps-extensions-console

Anyone knows how to create a Gmail Contextual Gadget?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest :
https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Go on that link a for log in use your Google Apps for bussiness account , then create new project (gadget) and then you can upload manifet. Sorry for my English.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Did you ever find where a manifest is uploaded in the new console?

Comment: @TonyBenBrahim did you find where to upload manifest file in new console?

Comment: No, I gave up on contextual gadgets and wrote browser extensions instead.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so the [Gmail Contextual Gadgets](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets?hl=en) doc says "Gmail contextual gadgets can be listed for sale in the Google Apps Marketplace". The [Google Apps Marketplace docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing) say apps can be published on the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard) but the web store seems to want some sort of .json manifest file that doesn't fit the documentation for Contextual Gadgets (read: Google's documentation is terrible).

Instead, I found a section inside the developer's console on Contextual Gadgets. It's also different from the documentation, but seems like the right spot.

1. Open your [Google developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/)
2. Select or create a project
3. Open the [Google Apps Marketplace SDK](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/appsmarket_component/overview) page
4. Click "Enable API"
5. Click "Configuration"
6. Check the box marked "Gmail contextual gadget extension"

There are then options to fill out info on the Contextual Gadget.

Comment: From what I can tell, the info you enter here is the same as would be found in the so called application manifest. From that I can only assume that the system with uploading a application manifest-file no longer is maintained and we need to use this GUI instead. If so, good thing this is all in the documentation, eh?